# How can I implement Player Prefs to Save High scores in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, mobile

I am new to both unity and C# and facing trouble in saving and displaying  the highscore.text in the game.Til now I only successfully managed to display the scoreUI and update them whenever player hits the enemy.This is the code that I'm using.

```
{

public GameObject ScoreImage;
public Text scoreTextUI;

int score;
public int Score
{
    get
    {
        return this.score;
    }
    set
    {
        this.score = value;
        UpdateScoreTextUI();
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    //Get the Text UI Component of this gameObject   
    scoreTextUI = GetComponent<Text> ();
}

void UpdateScoreTextUI()
{
    string scoreStr = string.Format ("{0:000000}", score);
    scoreTextUI.text = scoreStr;
}
}
```

Comment: Here is documentation about PlayerPrefs: [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) - there you can find code examples and information about platforms.

Comment: read them but still unable to figure out how to implement :(

Comment: Please show us your research effort. The API of PlayerPrefs is not that difficult so I am pretty sure you tried something. Describe to us what roadblock you were hitting.

Answer (score 1):

Saving `Int` to player prefs:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", 10);
```

Retriveing `Int` from player prefs:

```
var playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `PlayerPrefs` works on `Key-Value` mechanism just like `Dictionary`. The difference is that you can set `Key` only in `string`.

Unity provides very basic data types that can save using `PlayerPrefs`, that includes `int`,`float`, and `string`.

In your case you are going to save an integer value, that `PlayerPrefs` supports. You can use it through

```
/* Replace HIGH_SCORE_KEY with your string key 
and HIGH_SCORE_VALUE with your int score */
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HIGH_SCORE_KEY",HIGH_SCORE_VALUE)

// Similarly you can get the value as
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HIGH_SCORE_KEY");
```

Now what you have to make change in your code,

```
...
int _score = 0; // Assuming that you are updating this variable as score
string KEY_HIGH_SCORE = "keyhighscore"; // whatever you set, doesn't matter. Just store it in variable to avoid any typo

// To save highscore
int currentHighScore = PlayerPrefs(KEY_HIGH_SCORE); // If no score was saved corresponding to that key then it will return 0

if (currentHighScore < _score) // if stored score is less than the current score
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(KEY_HIGH_SCORE, _score);

// Get and update the scoreUI whenever and wherever you want as
int currentHighScore = PlayerPrefs(KEY_HIGH_SCORE); 
scoreTextUI.text = scoreStr.ToString();
```